# SQLite Aggregation then Transpose

Tags: aggregate, pivot, sqlite3

I am currently uploading my solar inverter data to PVOutput using a Linux machine and a scratch built Perl script. I want to add the meter data from my enrgy supplier. I have an 87,000 row CSV file downloaded from my energy supplier that contains the following (sample) data:

```
NMI,Meter Serial Number,Stream,Register Number,Register Description,UOM,ReadingDate,Units,Read Type<br>
700555,7006444,B,B1,Solar energy,kWh,23-09-21 23:45,0,      Actual
700555,7006444,E,E1,Offpeak,     kWh,23-09-21 23:45,0.093,  Actual
700555,7006444,B,B1,Solar energy,kWh,23-09-21 23:30,0,      Actual
700555,7006444,E,E1,Offpeak,     kWh,23-09-21 23:30,0.085,  Actual
700555,7006444,B,B1,Solar energy,kWh,23-09-21 23:15,0,      Actual
700555,7006444,E,E1,Offpeak,     kWh,23-09-21 23:15,0.085,  Actual
```

By creating a virtual column (MyDate) and using the following select:

```
select MyDate, "Register Description", sum(Units) 
from MeterData group by MyDate, "Register Description"
```

I have been able to massage the data in SQLite to give me:

```
20210920|Offpeak|3.821
20210920|Peak|4.954
20210920|Shoulder|5.695
20210920|Solar energy|2.958
20210921|Offpeak|3.831
20210921|Peak|4.41
20210921|Shoulder|4.428
20210921|Solar energy|4.354
20210922|Offpeak|4.355
20210922|Peak|6.572
20210922|Shoulder|1.961
20210922|Solar energy|7.217
```

But for upload to PVOutput, the format I'm looking for is:

```
20210919|Offpeak|3.514|Peak|8.453|Shoulder|7.445|Solar energy|2.792
20210920|Offpeak|3.821|Peak|4.954|Shoulder|5.695|Solar energy|2.958
20210921|Offpeak|3.831|Peak|4.410|Shoulder|4.428|Solar energy|4.354
20210922|Offpeak|4.355|Peak|6.572|Shoulder|1.961|Solar energy|7.217
```

As you can see, my SQL skills are weak, and any help would be most appreciated.

Phill.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple conditional aggregation should do the trick:

```
select
  MyDate,
  'Offpeak',
  sum(Units) filter (where "Register Description" = 'Offpeak'),
  'Peak',
  sum(Units) filter (where "Register Description" = 'Peak'),
  'Shoulder',
  sum(Units) filter (where "Register Description" = 'Shoulder'),
  'Solar energy',
  sum(Units) filter (where "Register Description" = 'Solar energy')
from MeterData
group by MyDate
```

An alternative syntax is to remove the `filter` and use `case`

```
sum(case when "Register Description" = 'Offpeak' then Units end)
```